# C#, using cshtml and sql, Error in page code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use cshtml and c# to create some dynamic pages.

My goal is when I go to admin/post/, I can add /new or /edit to get to where I want to go, however I'm getting a funky error in my browser which goes as follows:

System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' does not contain a definition for 'title'

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
**Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<object>' does not contain a definition for 'title'
Source Error: 
Line 8:  @if(!mode.IsEmpty())
Line 9:  {
Line 10:     var posted = Post.Current; // error is here
Line 11:     
Line 12:     <div>**
```

here is my code for post.cshtml:

```
@{
    var mode = Post.mode;
}

@if(!mode.IsEmpty())
{
    var posted = Post.Current;

    <div>
    <form name="post" method="post" action="~/admin/post.ashx">
        <input type="hidden" name="mode" value="@mode" />
        <p>Title: <input type="text" name="postTitle" value="@posted.title" /></p>
        <p>Content: <textarea name="postContent">@posted.content</textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="postSubmit" value="Create Post" /></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

and for my post class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages;
using System.Dynamic;
using WebMatrix.Data;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

public class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
    }

    private static WebPageRenderingBase page
    {
        get { return WebPageContext.Current.Page; }
    }

    public static String mode
    {
        get
        {
            if (page.UrlData.Any())
            {
                return page.UrlData[0];
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }

    }

    public static string Slug
    {
        get
        {
            if (mode == "edit")
            {
                return page.UrlData[1];
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public static dynamic Current
    {
        get
        {
            using (var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection"))
            {
                var sql = "SELECT * FROM table_posts WHERE Slug = @0";

                var result = db.Query(sql, Slug);

                return result ?? CreatePostObject();
            }
        }
    }

    private static dynamic CreatePostObject()
    {
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

        obj.title = String.Empty;
        obj.content = String.Empty;
        obj.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        obj.DatePublished = null;
        obj.Slug = String.Empty;
        obj.Authorid = null;

        return obj;
    }
```

---

```
public class PostHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public PostHandler()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var title = context.Request.Form["postTitle"];
        var content = context.Request.Form["postContent"];
        var slug = CreateSlug(title);


        using (var db = Database.Open("DefaultConnection"))
        {
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM table_posts WHERE Slug = @0";

            var result = db.QuerySingle(sql, slug);

            if (result != null)
            {
                throw new HttpException(409, "Slug gone bruh!");
            }

            sql = "INSERT INTO table_posts (title, content, authorid, slug) " +
                "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)";

            db.Execute(sql, title, content, 1, slug);

            context.Response.Redirect("~/admin/post/");
        }
    }

    public static String CreateSlug(String title)
    {
        title = title.ToLowerInvariant().Replace(" ", "-");
        title = Regex.Replace(title, @"[^0-9a-z-]", String.Empty);

        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean my friend

Comment: this is my post handler if it helps:

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: its native to one of the System repositories.

Comment: should i use a different object/

Comment: If I didn't miss anything in the `.cshtml` code, in the huge code base :), how are you passing Model to the view? What is the Model type? When exactly are you getting this error, while View rendering?

Comment: Did you try putting a break point in the `Current` property and if the resultset returned from `db.Query(...)` having the `title` property/column in it? + May be you have such requirement but I am quite not sure why are you using Handlers instead of MVC Controllers. Also since you are expecting to have certain properties on your dynamic object, why shouldn't you create a Model class to hold those properties and assign that data?